# Lazy loading of a uitableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a Navigation Controller. When user taps a button a new UIViewController is pushed into the stack. This new view retrieves some information from a google api and shows it in a tableview. My problem is that the tableview isn't showing. I retrieve the info once the view has loaded so I can show an activity indicator.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    centersNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    placesFromXml = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    vicinity = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self ParseXML_of_Google_PlacesAPI];
    [self.tableview reloadData]; //Doesn't work
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

How can I make the tableview appear after loading the info?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English.

Comment: have you set the UITableView's data source?

Comment: Maybe if you post some more code. Otherwise I can only guess. Did you check, that the Arrays that contain the data are really filled with data after the parsing?

Comment: Yes. If I locate that code in viewDidLoad the table shows fine with all the content. But the UI is frozen in the previous view of the navigation stack until the content from the xml is loaded. That's why I'm trying to load the table after the view is showed so I can load the content in other thread. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution. The problem was the navigation controller wasn't calling viewWillAppear, etc. Solution found here:

http://davidebenini.it/2009/01/03/viewwillappear-not-being-called-inside-a-uinavigationcontroller/